# Is my cucumber bitten?

Tags: identification

This is the first time I am growing cucumbers. I have really little knowledge when it comes to cucumbers.

I have noticed that there is a small spot in my cucumber. Can it be that a beetle or another insect has injected the “bitter” juice into it? Or is it just a cucumber thorn come off? Please help......
Thanks[image: Cucumber]!